# Do sulfites cook out?

Tags: wine, allergy, reduction

Do sulfites cook out when you reduce wine?

The main cooking mode I'm thinking of is a braise: coq au vin or beef Bourguignon, but would also be interested in the shorter cooking time recipes, e.g. a wine reduction pan sauce.

Comment: According to wikipedia, potassium metabisulfite (the most common sulfite used in winemaking) breaks down at 190 C, and one of the components (SO2) would outgas.  But much of it has already been converted to SO2 during the bottling process already...

Comment: At 190C and in the presence of water, does SO2 not become sulphurous acid and reenters the sauce?

Answer (score 2):

hmmm... I know that cooking (wine and other) alcoholic beverages will burn off the alcohol content, but according to [this article](https://www.wired.com/2015/06/wine-sulfites-fine-heres-remove-anyway/https://www.wired.com/2015/06/wine-sulfites-fine-heres-remove-anyway/), *Hydrogen Peroxide* will remove sulfites through oxidation. Go figure.